# Multi-factor authentication (password and key) with Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

I've got the following code:

```
import paramiko
policy = paramiko.client.WarningPolicy()
client = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(policy)
username = '...'
password = '...'
file_path = '...'
pkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(file_path)
client.connect('...', username=username, password=password, pkey=key)
sftp = client.open_sftp()
```

From the docs, it seems like it should work. Everything works successfully, but when the code hits `client.open_sftp` it bombs with a `SSHException: Unable to open channel.` and the transport (from `client.get_transport`) is active but not authenticated. I'm also having trouble enabling debug logging for this (I'm trying `logging.getLogger('paramiko').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` without success.)

Any ideas on where I can start to debug this very vague error message?

Answer (score 15):

Sorry for the late response but this problem was really hard to find any information on so i wanted to post a solution for anyone else stuck on this issue.

After pulling my hair out trying to solve this I found a solution thanks to some code posted by Doug Ellwanger and Daniel Brownridge. The problem seems to be caused by the way the multi-factor authentication is handled using more of an interactive style.

```
import paramiko
import threading

... 

username = '...'
password = '...'
file_path = '...'
pkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(file_path)
sftpClient = multifactor_auth('...', 22, username, pkey, password)

...

def multifactor_auth_sftp_client(host, port, username, key, password):
    #Create an SSH transport configured to the host
    transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
    #Negotiate an SSH2 session
    transport.connect()
    #Attempt authenticating using a private key
    transport.auth_publickey(username, key)
    #Create an event for password auth
    password_auth_event = threading.Event()
    #Create password auth handler from transport
    password_auth_handler = paramiko.auth_handler.AuthHandler(transport)
    #Set transport auth_handler to password handler
    transport.auth_handler = password_auth_handler
    #Aquire lock on transport
    transport.lock.acquire()
    #Register the password auth event with handler
    password_auth_handler.auth_event = password_auth_event
    #Set the auth handler method to 'password'
    password_auth_handler.auth_method = 'password'
    #Set auth handler username
    password_auth_handler.username = username
    #Set auth handler password
    password_auth_handler.password = password
    #Create an SSH user auth message
    userauth_message = paramiko.message.Message()
    userauth_message.add_string('ssh-userauth')
    userauth_message.rewind()
    #Make the password auth attempt
    password_auth_handler._parse_service_accept(userauth_message)
    #Release lock on transport
    transport.lock.release()
    #Wait for password auth response
    password_auth_handler.wait_for_response(password_auth_event)
    #Create an open SFTP client channel
    return transport.open_sftp_client()
```

I hope this helps, it worked for my project.

Comment: Paramiko can usually handle correctly on its own (at least in most cases). No need for such a complicated solution. For some example or a rare cases when Paramiko fails, see [Paramiko/Python: Keyboard interactive authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55498370/850848) - though even then there are simpler solutions then the low-level code in this answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. To make your answer complete, also add "import threading" to the code.

Comment: Thanks!! I tried several ways but your answer is the only that works!

Comment: To complement my comment above, I have added [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28837089/850848#68949359) with more details.

Comment: This is the only answer that works for me too.

Comment: Would you please explain *exactly* what kind of multi-factor authentication this code implements? For example, does the server generate some kind of challenge for every new connection that you have to process and answer?

Comment: this is the only solution I found for the exception `Oops, unhandled type 3 ('unimplemented')`

Answer (score 2):

In your script you declare

```
pkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(file_path)
```

and then instead of pkey, you have `pkey = key`.

Not sure what key is coming from but that might be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use this solution on [paramiko's github](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/894#issuecomment-279601951) found from a still-open issue (at the time of writing this). I'll include the original solution from that github issue, and the slight variant i use in my own code.

From jacky15 in that github issue:

```
import paramiko
paramiko.util.log_to_file('/path/to/log')
hostname = 'server.name'
port = 12345
username = 'username'
password = 'password' 
pkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('/path/to/key')

transport = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
transport.connect()

# auth the public key as usual, auth service now is activated on server 
transport.auth_publickey(username=username, key=pkey)

# try to send another userauth request without request auth service
m = paramiko.Message()
m.add_byte(paramiko.common.cMSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST)
m.add_string(username)
m.add_string('ssh-connection')
m.add_string('password')
m.add_boolean(False)
py3_password = paramiko.py3compat.bytestring(password)
m.add_string(py3_password)
transport._send_message(m)

# now it works! : )
sftp_client = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
```

from my code:

```
transport = paramiko.Transport((self.hostname, self.port))
transport.start_client(event=None, timeout=30)
transport.get_remote_server_key()
my_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(self.hostkey)
transport.auth_publickey(self.username, my_key)
m = paramiko.Message()
m.add_byte(paramiko.common.cMSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST)
m.add_string(self.username)
m.add_string('ssh-connection')
m.add_string('password')
m.add_boolean(False)
py3_password = paramiko.py3compat.bytestring(self.password)
m.add_string(py3_password)
transport._send_message(m)
self.connection = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
```

Answer (score -2):

The Paramiko high-level API, `SSHClient` can handle common two-factor authentication on its own. For example for key and password authentication, use:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect(
    "example.com", username="username", password="password",
    key_filename="/path/to/key")
```

---

So the complicated code in the answer by @osekmedia is usually not needed.

I know of only two scenarios, where it can "help":

1. `SSHClient` by default verifies the host key. You may mistake failure to verify the host key with failure of the two-factor authentication. They are not related. It's just that the low-level `Transport` API, that the @osekmedia's code uses, does not verify the host key, what avoids your actual problem. But that's a security flaw. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883).
2. You might think that you are using password authentication, while you actually use keyboard-interactive authentication. Normally Paramiko can handle keyboard-interactive authentication, even if you mistakenly ask for password authentication. But with some obscure servers, this does not work, see [Password authentication in Python Paramiko fails, but same credentials work in SSH/SFTP client](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55498370/850848#55501808). In such case, the following code should do:

   ```
   username = "username"

   transport = paramiko.Transport('example.com') 
   transport.connect(username=username)

   key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("/path/to/key")
   transport.auth_publickey(username, key)

   def handler(title, instructions, fields):
       if len(fields) > 1:
           raise SSHException("Expecting one field only.")
       return ["password"]

   transport.auth_interactive(username, handler)
   ```

   Note that the above code uses `Transport`, so it by default bypasses host key verification. Use `hostkey` argument of the `Transport.connect` to correct that.

Comment: Why is this answer -2? downvoters please explain.