# sFTP with SSH Key & Password in Python

Tags: python, pysftp

Trying to use pysftp to pull files from an sFTP server that requires both ssh key & password for authentication without much luck.  Can use pysftp with just key and just password, but it breaks when I attempt to use both.  Hoping someone has some experience with this.  Open to using a different library if that works better.

Error output is:

paramiko.ssh_exception.BadAuthenticationType: Bad authentication type; allowed types: ['publickey']

```
import pysftp


connection_host = '1.1.1.1'
connection_user = 'username'
connection_password = 'password'
connection_private_key = '/path/to/key'
connection_dir='/dir/on/remote/host'

with pysftp.Connection(host=connection_host, username=connection_user, password=connection_password, private_key=connection_private_key) as sftp:
    files = sftp.listdir(remotepath=connection_dir)

    for file in files:
        print("found the following file: {}".format(file))
        with sftp.cd(connection_dir):
            sftp.get(file)
```

Comment: Post [Paramiko log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27587716/850848). + Output of `ssh -vvv ...` when successfully authenticating to the same server from the same local machine. + See [Two factor (key and keyboard-interactive) authentication to SFTP server using Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56782531/850848) and [Multi-factor authentication (password and key) with Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28837089/850848#68949359).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl thank you VERY much.  Thanks to your guidance I was able to resolve, using paramiko

Answer (score 4):

Working code if anyone runs into the same issue:

```
connection_host = '0.0.0.0'
connection_user = 'username'
connection_password = 'password'
connection_private_key = '/path/to/key.pem'
connection_dir='/remote/path'


ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy)

ssh.connect(connection_host, username=connection_user, password=connection_password, key_filename=connection_private_key)
sftp_client = ssh.open_sftp()

files = sftp_client.listdir(connection_dir)
sftp_client.chdir(connection_dir)

for file in files:
    print("found the following file {}".format(file))
    sftp_client.get(file,file)

if sftp_client:
    sftp_client.close()

if ssh:
    ssh.close()
```

Comment: Using `AutoAddPolicy` this way is a security flaw. See [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883).

Comment: Also it would be nice, if your question says explicitly what is the key point of your solution. I assume it was the use of the `password` and `key_filename` as per my answer at [Multi-factor authentication (password and key) with Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28837089/850848#68949359).